# User Environment - Error!

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, networking, thin-client

am using Windows 2003 as OS for my thin-client server.

From last two days, I am getting error when user logs in at the user end.

Error is - Windows cannot log you on because your profile cannot be loaded. Check that you are connected to the network, or that your network is functioning correctly. If this problem persists, contact your network administrator.

After this message users are not able to login, and once the server is restarted users are able to log-in.

Answer (score 0):

### Default User Folder Available?

check the Default User folder whether it had been deleted from C:\Documents and Settings. If it is missing than it will prevent new user profiles from being created as there was no default profile to pull the data from. Copying the Default User folder from a different computer over to the problem machine may resolved the issue. 
*

> Note: Default User is a hidden folder,
>   so be sure to turn on show hidden
>   files and folders before concluding
>   that the folder does not exist.

You may also wish to check this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837115